# Compare today's date with date in DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

I'd like to update my original question, I've figured out how to convert getDate() to today's date. But is there a way to change the field from datetime to date when I do the query? For example:

```
 Select CreatedDate from MyTable
```

So that CreatedDate is in Datetime, but when I do that select statement, can I convert it to date?

Comment: getdate() has a timestamp and I'm guessing your createddate field also has one, you would need to cast to date

Answer (score 1):

To compare dates, you can either use the `CAST` or `CONVERT` functions.
So answering both variations of your question, you can have something like this -

```
SELECT *
FROM [Data_Extension]
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, CreatedDate) = CONVERT(DATE, GetDate())
```

I prefer to use `CONVERT` since it allows you to choose a format of the date. Check options [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp). Also, you can use the function to transform the timestamp from `GetDate()` to the only date and compare it to your field's value.